# Audio playing in Safari when getting access to the microphone

Tags: javascript, api, audio, safari, microphone

I want to allow a user to listen to an audio and then be able to record a new audio. The problem is that on Safari, once I run the code to get access to the microphone, it re-plays the last audio that was played.

I have code that looks something like this:

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false }).then(stream => {
  // at this point Safari will play the last audio
  });
```

Is there some buffer that needs to be cleared? How I can I prevent the last audio played from being re-played here?

Comment: if at some point you decide you need a more flexible audio framework for browsers read up on Web Audio API

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working in my case was removing the `autoplay` attribute of my audio elements.